# MYSQL Group By Having as HQL

Tags: mysql, sql, hql

I have a mysql query that returns all of my data. I need a sum of the total but can't use a sub-select because I am actually doing this in HQL.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
    COUNT(*) as records,
    SUM(_account_orders.calculatedTotal)
 FROM 
    SwAccount as _account 
LEFT JOIN
    SwOrder as _account_orders ON _account.accountID = _account_orders.accountID
GROUP BY 
    _account.accountID 
HAVING SUM(_account_orders.calculatedTotal) >= 10
```

Result:

```
records     SUM(_account_orders.calculatedTotal)    
----------  --------------------------------------- 
 1           11                                      
 1           150                                     
 1           4435.12                                 
 3           13463.36                                
 1           19.95                                   
 1           1126.12                                 
 2           39.98                                   
 5           19431.55                                
 1           300                                     
 1           2498                                    
 1           294.71                                  
 1           109.99                                  
 1           55                                      
 1           458.42                                  
 1           200                                     
 4           2166.94
```

I need this to return the count of 26 instead of the current result where its giving the sum for each row. I need the sum of all the rows. I will then turn it into HQL once I have a correct result. HQL doesn't allow the subselect in this case, so need a way without. With mssql you can use a count(*) OVER() to do this. Mysql version would use the sub-select. Can this be done in HQL?

Comment: Could you create a view for what you have, and select from that view the sum over its rows?

Comment: @trincot I believe a view won't work in this case because we use ORM and the view would need to work across mysql, mssql, and oracle. Its a good idea though.